# ImportError: cannot import name 'PandasError'

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-datareader

I am very new to Python 3x, running on a mac.

Currently using a sentdex tutorial for python with finance, tried running the following script:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

style.use('ggplot')

start = dt.datetime(2000,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2016,12,31)

df = web.DataReader('TSLA', 'yahoo', start, end)
print(df.head())
```

However this returns the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Downloads\Python Work\try figuring thigns out\finance\try.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas_datareader.data as web
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .data import (get_components_yahoo, get_data_famafrench, get_data_google, get_data_yahoo, get_data_enigma,  # noqa
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader.google.daily import GoogleDailyReader
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\google\daily.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader.base import _DailyBaseReader
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader._utils import (RemoteDataError, SymbolWarning,
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\_utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pandas.core.common import PandasError
ImportError: cannot import name 'PandasError'
```

I think maybe there's something wrong with panda-datareader itself, which I've ensured has been upgraded to most recent version (pandas-datareader 0.3.0.post0)

Is there an older version I can install instead? I've been using pip3 to install via mac terminal.

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 18):

I think you installed pandas v. 0.20.1 released yesterday.
pandas-datareader is still not compatible with this version, for the moment you should stay on pandas 0.19.2:

```
pip install -U pandas==0.19.2
```

Comment: Great !! This version works. Thanks very much for your swift answer!

Answer (score 5):

The latest version of `pandas_datareader` (`0.5.0`) takes care of this import error. You can install it with `pip`:

```
sudo pip install -U pandas_datareader
```

Answer (score 0):

I may already be too late to the discussion but I encountered this earlier today using a brand new Azure Compute that I spun up, I did all the steps above and was always encountering the error.

It may not be explicitly stated above but restarting the kernel AFTER the steps above fixed the issue.