# Pyfolio Import Error

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

When I simply just import pyfolio, I found this error. I've searched on internet, I found some posts saying it's the API issue BTW data provider and pandas(never able to get yahoo data anyway). However, I couldn't find a way to solve it. Is there anyone can help me with this please?

Thanks a lot for your time.

**My version of pandas and pyfolio is below:**

```
pyfolio(0.8.0)
pandas(0.20.3)
pandas-datareader(0.3.0.post0)
```

`import pyfolio`

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       import pyfolio
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyfolio__init__.py", line 3, in 
>       from . import utils
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyfolio\utils.py", line 24, in 
>       import empyrical.utils
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\empyrical__init__.py", line 21, in 
>       from .stats import (
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\empyrical\stats.py", line 23, in 
>       from .utils import nanmean, nanstd, nanmin, up, down, roll, rolling_window
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\empyrical\utils.py", line 26, in 
>       from pandas_datareader import data as web
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader__init__.py", line 3, in 
>       from .data import (get_components_yahoo, get_data_famafrench, get_data_google, get_data_yahoo, get_data_enigma,  # noqa
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 7, in 
>       from pandas_datareader.google.daily import GoogleDailyReader
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\google\daily.py", line 1, in 
>       from pandas_datareader.base import _DailyBaseReader
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 13, in 
>       from pandas_datareader._utils import (RemoteDataError, SymbolWarning,
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader_utils.py", line 5, in 
>       from pandas.core.common import PandasError
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'PandasError'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name 'PandasError'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43809620/importerror-cannot-import-name-pandaserror)

Comment: i tried as well, i uninstalled the pandas-datareader, now when i am trying to reinstall, it said failed to build wheel for wrapt... any idea of this pls?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be issue with PyFolio release.

Look at [similar issue](https://github.com/quantopian/pyfolio/issues/387) at GitHub.

Install latest version from clone of GitHub
[repository](https://github.com/quantopian/pyfolio.git) , that should solve the issue otherwise you need to open a issue at GitHub.

There are similar issues about Yahoo URL failures on the site.

You seem to have old version of `pandas-datareader` [latest version](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is **0.6.0** as of today. And please see that Yahoo API has been deprecated lately

> **Warning**
>
> As of v0.6.0 Yahoo!, Google Options, Google Quotes and EDGAR have been
> immediately deprecated due to large changes in their API and no stable
> replacement.